# How do I find an item in an array of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have this:

```
list = [ { 'p1':'v1' } ,{ 'p2':'v2' } ,{ 'p3':'v3' } ]
```

I need to find p2 and get its value.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that only one dict in the list has the key you want?

Comment: yes @Wooble, the values "v1","v2"... from the dictionaries are always different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what your actual code looks like (each key is unique), you should just use one dictionary:

```
things = { 'p1':'v1', 'p2':'v2', 'p3':'v3' }
do_something(things['p2'])
```

You can convert a list of dictionaries to one dictionary by merging them with `update` (but this will overwrite duplicate keys):

```
dict = {}
for item in list:
    dict.update(item)
do_something(dict['p2'])
```

If that's not possible, you'll need to just loop through them:

```
for item in list:
    if 'p2' in item:
        do_something(item['p2'])
```

If you expect multiple results, you can also build up a list:

```
p2s = []
for item in list:
    if 'p2' in item:
        p2s.append(item['p2'])
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend actually naming any variables `dict` or `list`, since that will cause problems with the built-in `dict()` and `list()` functions.

Comment: I used the name "list" for this array just for this example only, thanks for the answer and the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following ... That will return all the values equivilant to the givenKey in all dictionaries.

```
ans = [d[key] for d in list if d.has_key(key)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in list:
    if d.has_key("p2"):
        return d['p2']
```

Comment: haskey should be has_key or, better yet, just 'in', as in '"p2" in d'

Answer (score 1):

These shouldn't be stored in a list to begin with, they should be stored in a dictionary. Since they're stored in a list, though, you can either search them as they are:

```
lst = [ { 'p1':'v1' } ,{ 'p2':'v2' } ,{ 'p3':'v3' } ]
p2 = next(d["p2"] for d in lst if "p2" in d)
```

Or turn them into a dictionary:

```
dct = {}
any(dct.update(d) for d in lst)
p2 = dct["p2"]
```

Comment: You said these shouldnt be stored in a list, is this comment specific to this question or generally to avoid arrays of dicts ? What if the dict have the same set of keys ?

Comment: I know this is old, but just gotta add: when you say "These shouldn't be stored in a list to begin with", sometimes one doesn't get to make the design choice! I'm using an API that's providing info exactly as the OP described: a list of dictionaries, each containing only one key-value pair. I don't know why the API designer chose to do that, but I'm stuck with their choice. I *do* appreciate the options you provide for resolution!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one-liner:

```
filter(lambda x: 'p2' in x, list)[0]['p2']
```

if you have more than one 'p2', this will pick out the first; if you have none, it will raise IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a oneoff lookup, you can do something like this

```
>>> [i['p2'] for i in my_list if 'p2' in i]
['v2']
```

If you need to look up multiple keys, you should consider converting the list to something that can do key lookups in constant time (such as a dict)

```
>>> my_list = [ { 'p1':'v1' } ,{ 'p2':'v2' } ,{ 'p3':'v3' } ]
>>> my_dict = dict(i.popitem() for i in my_list)
>>> my_dict['p2']
'v2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by flattening the list of dictionaries out to a dictionary, then you can index it by key and get the value:

```
{k:v for x in list for k,v in x.iteritems()}['p2']
```